# Graphql - Query returns null

Tags: graphql, graphql-java

I am using the **graphql-java-annotations** library for java to retrieve data from my spring backend.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.github.graphql-java</groupId>
      <artifactId>graphql-java-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

When I call the query it always return null.

This is my Provider class:

```
GraphQLAnnotations graphqlAnnotations = new GraphQLAnnotations();
GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = newSchema()
            .query(graphqlAnnotations.object(QueryTest.class))
            .build();
this.graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();
```

This is the query:

```
@GraphQLName("queryTest")
public class QueryTest {

    @GraphQLField
    public static Test byId(final DataFetchingEnvironment env,         @GraphQLName("id") Long id) {
        return new Test();
    }
}
```

And finally the Test.class

```
@GraphQLName("Test")
public class Test {

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Test() {
        this("0");
    }

    public Test(String id) {
        this.setName("Name" + id);
        this.setId(id);
    }

    @GraphQLField
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @GraphQLField
    public String getId() {
        return id;
   }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

This is my call:

```
{ 
   "query" : "query queryTest { byId(id: 2) { getId } }",
   "operationName" : "queryTest"
}
```

And this is the result i get:

```
{
  "data": {
    "byId": null
  }
}
```

I debugged into the graphql execution and found out that schema contains TestClass and Test. So type and query are known. With this configuration I don't have a fetcher or a resolver.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

I had to change my Provider class in order to create the schema correctly via the AnnotationsSchemaCreator Builder:

```
GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = AnnotationsSchemaCreator.newAnnotationsSchema()
            .query(QueryTest.class)
            .typeFunction(new ZonedDateTimeFunction())
            .build();

this.graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema).build();
```